# How to get an AnchorEntity.position to align with a touch event

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, touch-event

I tap the screen to fire a laser:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(fireLaser(_:)))
arView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func fireLaser(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "LaserBeam", transform: arView.cameraTransform.matrix)
    arView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

I want the laser to go to where I actually tapped and disappear from there. In `touchesBegan` I get the `hitPosition` and eventually set it to the `AnchorEntity.position` when I place the object like so

```
if let hitPosition = hitPosition {
    anchorEntity.position = hitPosition
}
```

The problem is where I tap on the screen the laser goes to another position. For example if I tap on the bottom of the screen the laser is firing from the top of the screen and disappearing there, when it should occur from the bottom.

**How can I get the laser to go to where I tap?**

```
var hitPosition: SIMD3<Float>?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    guard let results = arView.hitTest(touch.location(in: arView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint]) else { return }
    guard let hitTest = results.last else { return }
    
    let transform = hitTest.worldTransform
    let hitPosition = SCNVector3(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z)
    
    let simd3Position = simd_float3(hitPosition)
    
    self.hitPosition = simd3Position
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        if let anchorName = anchor.name, anchorName == "LaserBeam" {
            placeObject(named: anchorName, for: anchor)
        }
    }
}

func placeObject(named entityName: String, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    
    do {
        
        let laserEntity = try ModelEntity.load(named: entityName)
        
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)

        if let hitPosition = hitPosition {
            anchorEntity.position = hitPosition
        }

        anchorEntity.addChild(laserEntity)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

screenshot of me tapping the bottom of the screen but the laser firing and disappearing from the top of the screen.

[image]